# How to build the C code of OpenJDK 8 src.zip /launcher/

Tags: java

I have downloaded the JDK 8.20: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

In there is a src.zip, which looks like an example for embedding, but there is no makefile or other build script.

The directory /launcher/ contains the files:

```
defines.h
emessages.h
java.c
java.h
java_md.h
java_md_common.c
java_md_solinux.c
java_md_solinux.h
jli_util.c
jli_util.h
main.c
manifest_info.h
parse_manifest.c
splashscreen.h
splashscreen_stubs.c
version_comp.c
version_comp.h
wildcard.c
wildcard.h
```

I made this little build.sh-script:

```
# -m32 = 32bit for embedding
# -I. for fake jvm.h, because it does not exist and fails on including it otherwise
options="-m32 -I/root/openjdk8/jdk1.8.0_20/include/ -I/root/openjdk8/jdk1.8.0_20/include/linux/ -I."

echo "COMPILE java.c"
gcc -c java.c -o java.o $options

echo "COMPILE java_md_common.c"
gcc -c java_md_common.c -o java_md_common.o $options

echo "COMPILE java_md_solinux.c"
gcc -c java_md_solinux.c -o java_md_solinux.o $options

echo "COMPILE jli_util.c"
gcc -c jli_util.c -o jli_util.o $options

echo "COMPILE main.c"
gcc -c main.c -o main.o $options

echo "COMPILE parse_manifest.c"
gcc -c parse_manifest.c -o parse_manifest.o $options

echo "COMPILE splashscreen_stubs.c"
gcc -c splashscreen_stubs.c -o splashscreen_stubs.o $options

echo "COMPILE version_comp.c"
gcc -c version_comp.c -o version_comp.o $options

echo "COMPILE wildcard.c"
gcc -c wildcard.c -o wildcard.o $options
```

These errors occur:

```
./build.sh
COMPILE java.c
java.c: In function âContinueInNewThreadâ:
java.c:1885:29: error: storage size of âargs1_1â isnât known
COMPILE java_md_common.c
java_md_common.c: In function âProgramExistsâ:
java_md_common.c:67:17: error: storage size of âsbâ isnât known
java_md_common.c:70:26: error: âS_IEXECâ undeclared (first use in this function)
java_md_common.c:70:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
java_md_common.c: In function âJLI_ReportErrorMessageSysâ:
java_md_common.c:155:21: error: âerrnoâ undeclared (first use in this function)
java_md_common.c: In function âProcessDirâ:
java_md_common.c:214:5: error: unknown type name âDIRâ
java_md_common.c:222:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
java_md_common.c:226:17: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
java_md_common.c:228:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c:229:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c:231:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c:233:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c:236:46: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c:237:67: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c:239:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c:242:48: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
java_md_common.c: In function âFindBootStrapClassâ:
java_md_common.c:494:59: error: âRTLD_DEFAULTâ undeclared (first use in this function)
COMPILE java_md_solinux.c
java_md_solinux.c:27:20: fatal error: jvm_md.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
COMPILE jli_util.c
COMPILE main.c
In file included from main.c:33:0:
defines.h:37:2: error: #error "FULL_VERSION must be defined"
defines.h:44:2: error: #error "JDK_MAJOR_VERSION and JDK_MINOR_VERSION must be defined"
main.c: In function âmainâ:
main.c:128:20: error: âFULL_VERSIONâ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:128:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:129:20: error: âDOT_VERSIONâ undeclared (first use in this function)
COMPILE parse_manifest.c
COMPILE splashscreen_stubs.c
COMPILE version_comp.c
COMPILE wildcard.c
```

Does anybody know how to compile it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently facing the same problem. Maybe it can be solved by providing jvm.h and jvm_md.h for your setup.
Both contain-jvm-specific symbols and jvm_md.h contains additionally platform-dependent symbols. So you will need to choose jvm.h for your target jvm and jvm_md.h for your target platform. To get these headers for Oracle's OpenJDK8, go to http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/ and download the sources. (For Java 7 it's http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/ etc)

Within this file, you will find jvm.h in the folder
/openjdk/jdk/src/share/javavm/export/

jvm_md.h is in folder:
/openjdk/jdk/src/[target platform]/javavm/export/

Note that this path does not exist for Linux and Bsd (/openjdk/jdk/src/[target platform] only contains docs in these cases). I believe - however - that the Solaris-version is intended to serve these systems too.

Hope this helps...